# Tracking internal link php

Tags: php, statistics

I want to set up a few internal statistics for one of my dynamic sites. The idea is to make available to each member of the site:
a) How many times the profile has been seen in the day (1 click = 1 ip = 1 view)
b) How many times the profile has been seen in the month (1 click = 1 ip = 1 view)
c) How many have left since the mail button "contact".

Before developing this in php, I wanted to know if you would not have a resource that these actions. It would save me some time.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I create my own internal link tracker for ZF.

I don't use cookie.

I check if an ip is already back on the site. If so, I change the date of last visit, otherwise I created. Then, I check if the called page has already been visited. If so, I change, otherwise I insert. Then, I check if the association ip / page exists: if so, I change, otherwise I insert.

In the end, I can have a system of click per day, month, year, and for su ...

I wrote a tutorial on the occasion on my blog, because now it is only really suited to the current project.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would just simply need to have a DB where you could save those statistics. Then, you would create a class with a few functions that save statistics to this DB. E.g.

```
function addPageview($pageIdentifier, $loggedInUser) {
    // code to save to DB
}
```

Then, when a page is viewed (e.g. the profile page of someone), you do a call to this addPageview() with the correct page identifier (e.g. the URL) and the logged in User so you know who has viewed the page. You leave $user empty if there is no logged in user.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to increase your profile-views counter by 1, you can restrict this to do so every 24 hours by setting a cookie on the visitors computer with that specific users ID. The user can clear their cookies and visit the profile again, but "commoners" dont know about this technique.

In your code for viewing the profile, you use the following pseudocode:

```
if user has no cookie
   bump views up by 1
```